# Stopwatch verilog- Warnings

Tags: verilog

Can any one help me with the following warnings ?

```
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <ok1> of sequential type is unconnected in block <Control>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <ok2> of sequential type is unconnected in block <Control>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <bloc/ok3> of sequential type is unconnected in block <Main>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <bloc/ok0> of sequential type is unconnected in block <Main>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <bloc/seen> of sequential type is unconnected in block <Main>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <bloc/ok> of sequential type is unconnected in block <Main>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <bloc/i_3> of sequential type is unconnected in block <Main>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <bloc/i_2> of sequential type is unconnected in block <Main>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <bloc/i_1> of sequential type is unconnected in block <Main>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <bloc/i_0> of sequential type is unconnected in block <Main>.
```

```
module Control(
    startstop,
    clk,
    reset,
    PB_1,
    PB_2,
    PB_3,
    out_control,
    out_numarator,
    seen
);
input reset;
input startstop;
input clk;
input PB_1;
input PB_2;
input PB_3;
output reg [15:0] out_control;
input wire [15:0] out_numarator;
output seen;
reg seen=0;
reg [3:0] i=0;

reg ok0=0;
reg ok=0;
reg ok1=0;
reg ok2=0;
reg ok3=0;

reg [15:0] b1_var=0;
reg [15:0] b2_var=0;
reg [15:0] b3_var=0;

always@(posedge clk)
begin
    if (startstop==1) //BLOCUL PENTRU BUTONUL DE STARTSTOP
    begin
        ok=1;
        seen=1;
    end

    if(ok==1&&startstop==0)
    begin
        i=i+1;
        ok=0;
    end

    if(seen==1||reset==1)
        out_control=out_numarator;

    if(i==1&&ok0==0)//PRIMA APASARE A BUTONULUI STARTSTOP-- PORNESTE NUMARAREA
    begin
        b1_var=0;
        b2_var=0;
        b3_var=0;
        ok0=1;
        ok1=0;
        ok2=0;
        ok3=0;
    end
    if(i==2&&ok1==0)//A DOUA APASARE ---MEMOREAZA 
    begin
        b1_var=out_numarator;
        ok1=1;
    end
    if( i==3&&ok2==0)//A 3-A APASARE --MEMOREAZA
    begin
        b2_var=out_numarator;
        ok2=1;
    end
    if(i==4&&ok3==0)// A 4-A APASARE MEMOREAZA SI OPRESTE CRONOMETRUL
    begin
        b3_var=out_numarator;
        ok3=1;
        seen=0;
        i=0;
        ok0=0;
    end

    if(reset==1)
    begin
        ok=0;
        ok0=0;
        ok1=0;
        ok2=0;
        ok3=0;
        b1_var=0;
        b2_var=0;
        b3_var=0;
        i=0;
        seen=0;
    end

    if(PB_1==1)
    begin
        out_control=b1_var;
    end

    if(PB_2==1)
    begin
        out_control=b2_var;
    end

    if(PB_3==1)
    begin
        out_control=b3_var;
    end

end

endmodule
```

Comment: Please share `Main`. The warning might be from optimized out logic during synthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using the Verilog Non-Blocking Assignment operator `<=`

Replace all of your `=`s with `<=`

Also please come up with a better name for your signals!  `ok` `ok0` `ok1` etc is painful!

Comment: Why does he "need" to be using it? It is good practice to do so when creating clocked logic, but I'm not sure if/how it's related to those errors.

Comment: I agree with Tim. It is _good practice_ to use `<=` for flop assignments, but not related to these warnings. FYI, change form blocking to non-blocking will also require each of the `i==` conditions to subtract one; since `i`'s update is postponed to latter in the timestep.

Answer (score 0):

This warning usually happens when you have nodes from which there is not path to the output. For example, when you declare a variable as 16 bits, but only assign 8 bits of the variable to the outputs of your top module. Based on what you have shared, I am guessing Control is not the top module.

Check the path from these signals to your top module and verify that there is in fact a path from them to the outputs.

Note that sometimes although these paths exist in your code, the synthesizer optimizes them out.

More info here:

http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2010/03/synthesis-warning-node-of-sequential.html